# Wxwidget : Add image with zooming feature

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need to display an image on the panel. I got this working. The image can be of any type and it must support zooming feature. I was able to implement it using wxDC::SetUserScale(). But this zooming is with reference to center point. My question is how can i add the zooming feature that can zoom on any position in the image panel and not only the center.

Her is my code so far :

```
wxImagePanel::wxImagePanel(wxFrame* parent, wxImage img) :
wxPanel(parent)
{
    image = img.Copy();
    w = -1;
    h = -1;
    _factor = 0.25;
}

void wxImagePanel::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt)
{

    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void wxImagePanel::paintNow()
{
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void wxImagePanel::render(wxDC&  dc)
{
    int neww, newh;
    dc.GetSize(&neww, &newh);
    dc.Clear();
    dc.SetUserScale(_factor, _factor);
    dc.DrawBitmap(image, 0, 0);
    Update();
}

void wxImagePanel::OnSize(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
    Update();
    Refresh();
    event.Skip();
}

void wxImagePanel::_onZoom(wxMouseEvent &event)
{
    _xOffset /= _factor;
    _yOffset /= _factor;
    if (event.GetWheelRotation() > 0){
        if (_factor >= 1.f){
            _factor += 0.5f;
        }
        else{
            _factor *= 2.f;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (_factor > 1.f){
            _factor -= 0.5f;
        }
        else{
            _factor /= 2.f;
        }
    }
    _xOffset *= _factor;
    _yOffset *= _factor;

    if (_xOffset > image.GetWidth()*_factor - GetSize().GetWidth()){
        _xOffset = image.GetWidth()*_factor - GetSize().GetWidth();
    }
    if (_yOffset > image.GetHeight()*_factor - GetSize().GetHeight()){
        _yOffset = image.GetHeight()*_factor - GetSize().GetHeight();
    }

    paintNow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `_xOffset` and `_yOffset` as arguments to the `DrawBitmap` function. You'll also have to add some lines to calculate these offsets according to the mouse position when the wheel was turned (you should be able to get the coordinates by calling `event.GetLogicalPosition(wxClientDC(this))`, but am not 100% sure).

Comment: @BenChaabenAssil Second try: clip (a copy of) the image with the `GetSubImage` method